# Set Value of Input Using Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, input, yui, validation

I'm currently using a YUI gadget.  I also do have a Javascript function to validate the output that comes from the `div` that YUI draws for me:

```
Event.on("addGadgetUrl", "click", function(){
    var url = Dom.get("gadget_url").value;  /* line x ------>*/
    if (url == "") {
        error.innerHTML = "<p> error" /></p>";
    } else {
        /* line y ---> */ 
        /*  I need to add some code in here to set the value of "gadget_url" by "" */
    }
}, null, true);
```

Here is my `div`:

```
<div>
<p>URL</p>
<input type="text" name="gadget_url" id="gadget_url" style="width: 350px;" class="input"/>
<input type="button" id="addGadgetUrl" value="add gadget"/>
<br>
<span id="error"></span>
</div>
```

As you can see my question is, how can I set the value of `gadget_url` to be `""`?

Comment: Try...`Dom.get("gadget_url").set("value","");`...I'm not quite sure though

Answer (score 590, accepted):

### Javascript

```
document.getElementById('gadget_url').value = '';
```

### jQuery

```
$("#gadget_url").val("");
```

### YUI

```
Dom.get("gadget_url").set("value","");
```

Comment: `goodForm.coolinput.value='foo'`, is not possible, why can`t I use it instead of addressing the input directly by `id`? Wait, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42860401/1705829)..

Answer (score 87):

```
document.getElementById('gadget_url').value = '';
```

Comment: @Alastair I confirm - that is not using YUI. However OP in title write "Set Value of Input Using Javascript Function" (not YUI function) so answer meet question requirements

Answer (score 7):

The following works in MVC5:

```
document.getElementById('theID').value = 'new value';
```

Comment: javascript != MVC5

Comment: And yet he gave the correct answer. There are newbies that will find this question based on this answer.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the usecase it makes a difference whether you use javascript (`element.value = x`) or jQuery `$(element).val(x);`

When `x` is `undefined` jQuery results in an empty String whereas javascript results in `"undefined"` as a String.

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('gadget_url').value = 'your value';
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using YUI, but my issue was that I had duplicate ID's on the page (was working inside a dialog and forgot about the page underneath).

Changing the ID so it was unique allowed me to use the methods listed in [Sangeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700471/set-value-of-input-using-javascript-function/5700542#5700542).

Comment: Just for brevity and future reference, all id's on the page should **ALWAYS** be unique

Answer (score -5):

## Shortest

```
gadget_url.value=''
```

```js
addGadgetUrl.addEventListener('click', () => {
   gadget_url.value = '';
});
```

```html
<div>
  <p>URL</p>
  <input type="text" name="gadget_url" id="gadget_url" style="width: 350px;" class="input" value="some value" />
  <input type="button" id="addGadgetUrl" value="add gadget" />
  <br>
  <span id="error"></span>
</div>
```

This is the shortest working solution ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lamik/srpkju98/)).