# How do I return a value from a function in JavaScript to a textbox in HTML

Tags: javascript, textbox

This is my HTML code:

```
<head>

</head>

<body>

   LIMIT<input id='limit' name='' value='' class=''>

   <button id='go' class=''>GO</button>

   TOTAL<input id='total' name='' value='' class=''>

   <script src='js/limitfor.js'></script>


</body>
```

And this is my JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('go').onclick = function () {

 var limit = document.getElementById('limit').value;

 limit = parseFloat(limit);

 total = 0;

 for (i=0; i<=limit ;i++) {

     total = total + i;        

 };

};
```

---

If I alert the total, I can see that the function works, but I need the total to be in the textbox rather than in a pop up alert.

Comment: possible duplicate of [set value of input using JS function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700471/set-value-of-input-using-js-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to set the `value` of the input element:

```
document.getElementById("total").value = total;
```

Answer (score 2):

First select the particular element (i.e. total text field) in the form and set its value using assignment operator '='

```
document.getElementById("total").value=total;
```

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it could really help.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the value in total text box after your for loop is completed

```
 var limit = document.getElementById('limit').value;

 limit = parseFloat(limit);

 total = 0;

 for (i=0; i<=limit ;i++) {

   total = total + i;        

};
document.getElementById("total").value = total; 

};
```

Answer (score 0):

use `document.getElementById(put id of the text area where you want to output your answer or result).value = answer(whatever is your answer or result you want to reflect in textbox or textarea)`

[image]