# XPage : SSJS programatically stored values in Editboxes don‘t work

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

In an XPage I have a form with some `Editbox` fields for user input. The fields are writable.

For convinient test purposes I created an `Auto-Fill` Button which should fill in the form programmatically. There for I use some SSJS code triggered by a `Click Event`.

The Scipt code looks like this :

```
var id ='#{javascript:getClientId("company")}';
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML= 'Test company';
```

While this piece of code works best with `computedFields`, it doesn‘t work with `Editbox‘s`.

What do I miss here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`innerHTML` does not work for `input` element (Edit box renders as `input`). Use `value` instead: 
[Set Value of Input Using Javascript Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700471/set-value-of-input-using-js-function)

Comment: When I use value : `document.getElementById(id).value= 'Test company';` it does not work either .

Comment: You are right, it works as you stated. It does not work with my code because I embedded setting the value with in an `If (...)` statement. And that never becomes true. So it could not work.