# Using JS created variable in php, passing the variable

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to pass JS variable[array] to PHP. My idea is that javascript will print the array as a string with innerHTML to a div

`document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = variable;`

and if when I click on a POST button, PHP will collect it, but all of my attempts failed... :( Can someone help me, please? Is it even possible? Are there any better or working ways how to pass a variable to PHP from JS? I would rather avoid using AJAX and other stuff

Comment: Dear Atom, PHP is executed on server side and JS is executed on client side. So there is no you pass variable from JS --> PHP.  If you want to pass something to PHP then you need to invoke php apis.

Comment: yes... i know .. but the php will ask for the variable only after  it is created(by clicking to the button... )  it could transfer me to other side, it doesn't matter, i only need to save the variable...

Comment: Ajax is the only way to get data from PHP to js else you can try JSON encoder in PHP to transfer PHP JSON data to js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method I used in the past was to create a hidden form and set the value of each input with JavaScript or jQuery. Then on submit it will send the data to the PHP script.

EDIT: Here's the gist of it:

The hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenInput" value="">
```

Set the value with javascript:

```
document.getElementById('hiddenInput').value = 'value';
```

or set it with jQuery:

```
$("#hiddenInput").val('value');
```

Then send to PHP with submit button.

Comment: Not on hand, but this SO answer goes over it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700471/set-value-of-input-using-javascript-function

Comment: This actually works! :D You are a hero mr. Zach A...!! Thanks a lot!! :D :D