# Why cant i generate a random number?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to generate random number in this input box by clicking the button.. What is the problem here??

```js
 function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
    x.innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
 }
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<input type="text" name="demo" id="demo" value="" size="13" disabled="disabled" />
```

Comment: java != javascript

Comment: @Lino I do not think this is a duplicate question

Comment: @Lino, who said anything about Java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Set Value of Input Using Javascript Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700471/set-value-of-input-using-javascript-function)

Comment: @DanielB he tagged the question with a java tag

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `x.value` as this is a `input` element and it has `value` property and not `innerHTML` property.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  x.value = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<input type="text" name="demo" id="demo" value="" size="13" disabled="disabled" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use value instead of innerHTML

`x.value= Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);`