# How to Pass Object Value From A Javascript File to HTML File

Tags: javascript, html

I created an object with an array of products and I want to retrieve its value in a label in my html file but I don't know what's the right format. My javascript and html file are in separated files. Can someone help me with this. Thanks a lot!

```js
const database = [
  {
    name: "test",
    brand: "test",
    description: "test desc",
    price: "100",
  },
  {
    name: "test2",
    brand: "test brand",
    description: "test desc2",
    price: "200",
  },
  {
    name: "test3",
    brand: "test brand",
    " description": "test desc3",
    price: "300",
  },
];

function addToCart() {
  return console.log(database[0].name)
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
      <img src= "img/1.jpg" alt="Avatar">
      <div class="container">
        <span>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter items" id="productName" value=$database[0].name />
        <button onclick="addToCart()" id="addToCart">Buy</button>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean passing from a JS file to a HTML file? Are you maybe taking about [DOM manipulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents)?

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi Yes. I just don't know how to get or pass the value from my object and retrieve to my html element or what's the correct format to use to get the value.

Comment: Suggest you start with some javascript basics on how to set a value for an `<input>` using javascript. You should have no problem finding tutorials for doing it. SO is not  tutorial service to learn basics. It is expected you research the fundamentals yourself first

Comment: this require module if you know what is I can show the way but if you're beginner just go step by step

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set Value of Input Using Javascript Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700471/set-value-of-input-using-javascript-function)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const database = [
  {
    name: "test",
    brand: "test",
    description: "test desc",
    price: "100",
  },
  {
    name: "test2",
    brand: "test brand",
    description: "test desc2",
    price: "200",
  },
  {
    name: "test3",
    brand: "test brand",
    " description": "test desc3",
    price: "300",
  },
];

function addToCart() {
document.getElementById('productName').value = database[0].name;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
      <img src= "img/1.jpg" alt="Avatar">
      <div class="container">
        <span>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter items" id="productName"/>
        <button onclick="addToCart()" id="addToCart">Buy</button>
      </div>
 </div>
```

try this. it will work